# Expand the dataframe by a column value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Lets say I have a dataframe `df` in this format: I have shown for only `id = 1` but I have several `id` values.

```
  Email       id    Product   Value
x@gmail.com    1      p_1       1
y@gmail.com    1      p_2       2
z@gmail.com    1      p_3       3
t@gmail.com    1      p_4       4
```

Now I need the result in this format:

```
  Email       id    Product   Value  Product_n   Value_n
x@gmail.com    1      p_1       1        p_2        2
x@gmail.com    1      p_1       1        p_3        3
x@gmail.com    1      p_1       1        p_4        4
y@gmail.com    1      p_2       2        p_1        1
y@gmail.com    1      p_2       2        p_3        3
y@gmail.com    1      p_2       2        p_4        4   ....so on
```

I take in each item in `Product` of specific `id` and then create two new columns with the rest of the `Product` items.

I tried the same by using a `for` loop but for around 1000 `id` values and 9 `Product` items for each `id` it takes me lot of time. Can we make the process quicker.

```
product_items = df['Product'].unique()
for idx in range(1,(len(df['id'].unique())+1)):
    for i in product_items:
        for j in product_items:
            if j != i:
                df1 = df.loc[(df['id'] == idx) & (df['Product'] == i)]
                df2 = (df.loc[df['Product'] == j]).iloc[:,2:4]
                df_add = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis =1)
                df_final = df_final.append(df_add)
```

Comment: Don't quite understand how you build `Product_n` and `Value_n` columns

Comment: @sumanth - is my proposed solution working for you?

Comment: @MohamedThasinah i just tried it now, with few modifications - it helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
temp=df[['Product','Value']]
temp_df=pd.DataFrame()
for val in temp['Product'].unique().tolist():
    temp_df=pd.concat([temp_df,temp.copy().assign(key=val)])
df= pd.merge(df,temp_df,left_on=['Product'],right_on=['key'],how='right')
df=df.rename(columns={'Product_x':'Product','Value_x':'Value','Product_y':'Product_n','Value_y':'Value_n'})
df=df[df['Product']!=df['Product_n']]
```

Explanation:

1. temp contains only required columns, temp_df explodes your dataframe and assigns a key for merge
2. temp_df contains duplication of your main df to perform merge.
3. Do right join based on the product and key
4. clean up the data